# Port Forwarding from Virtualbox to my windows machine

Tags: tomcat, virtualbox, portforwarding

I have an application running inside my VirtualBox-based Ubuntu server. This application needs to call another web application which is hosted on port 8080 on my local VirtualBox host (i.e. outside the VM).

How can I access my local web application from within VirualBox?

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP address of your VirtualBox host to send requests to it from the guest.

If you are using bridged networking (for the VM), then your host's IP address is whatever it usually is. If you are using NAT, then your VM host should have an IP address on the same VLAN as the guest, but it might be a little more difficult to determine.

Switching to bridged-networking might help if you can't find the "internal" IP address of your guest.